# Как правильно подготовить изображения для android os в 2018г.?

Tags: android

Как в 2018г. подготавливаются изображения при разработке под Android os 5 и выше, насколько понял с 5 версии появилась поддержка svg и достаточно добавить одно изображение данного формата для иконок, правильно ли рисовать сложные формы для кнопок в xml или легче просто добавить png фон, также хочется понять с помощью каких прог лучше всего извлекать изображения (Sketch, XD, Photoshop), задавать координаты для xml(воспользовался Illustrator из svg добавлял координаты в xml)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Насколько понял с 5 версии появилась поддержка svg и достаточно добавить одно изображение данного формата для иконок?

Ответ: Да, поддержка есть и одного изображения в формате svg, будет достаточно

2. Правильно ли рисовать сложные формы для кнопок в xml или легче просто добавить png фон?

Ответ: Смотря какие цели Вы преследуете. Что правильно а что нет,будете решать Вы.
По сути любая кнопка в Android - это квадратная или прямоугольная область, а что помещено поверх этой области, решаете тоже Вы.
Svg избавит вас от необходимость делать по 5 разных размеров каждого изображения, ну весит намного меньше)

3. Также хочется понять с помощью каких прог лучше всего извлекать изображения?

Ответ: Sketch - Вам подойдет, это вообще очень удобное решение для дизайна интерфейса, будь то iphone или android,  но это решение работает исключительно yf Macbook.

Illustrator - соответственно можно использовать на windows. Можно рисовать как иконки так и интерфейсы.

Photoshop - только для png.

Comment: не SVG, а VectorDrawable, в который нужно конвертировать и который имеет ограничения (проще) SVG. С библиотекой поддержки использовать VectorDrawable можно и на устройствах ниже API21 (старше Anroid 5)